# Hadoop HDFS - executing JAR file on virtual machine

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, netbeans, hdfs

I have built a Java application with Maven in NetBeans. When I built Main project (Run -> build Main project) I got a JAR file called ROVKP_3zad-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar with only one class called Main.
Then I put that JAR file on Virtual Machine and tried to execute this from command line, from folder where the JAR file is placed:

```
hadoop jar ROVKP_3zad-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.rovkp_3zad.Main
```

And I got an error saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

What could be the cause? In my .pom file it is, besides other, defined:

```
 <name>ROVKP_3zad</name>
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
            <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
            </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

so I think there is not problem with dependencies and classpath. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Change your POM to:

```
 <name>ROVKP_3zad</name>
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
            <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>com.mycompany.rovkp_3zad.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
            </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: exactly you have to mention full path for class name (relative path wrt to package)